# Solve $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

To solve this I did $x = \arcsin(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$

However, my book states that the solution is $$x = \frac{\pi}{6}+k2\pi \lor x = \frac{5\pi}{6}+k2\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: well, arcsin always gives you only one solution, but of course sin is periodic so there's a lot more solutions than the one the arcsin gives you.. as a matter of fact, the arcsin always gives you the unique solution between $-\pi /2$ and $\pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcsine function 
$$\arcsin x: [-1, 1] \to \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
is defined by 
$$\arcsin x = y \iff \sin y = x, y \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
By finding 
$$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
you found the unique value of $x$ in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ such that $\sin x = 1/2$.  However, the solution set of the equation
$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$$
is the set of all angles that have sine $1/2$.

An angle in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) has sine $1/2$ if the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle at a point that has $y$-coordinate $1/2$.  You have shown that one such angle is $\pi/6$.  To find the others, consider the following diagram.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two angles have the same sine if the $y$-coordinates of the terminal side of the angle are equal.  Thus, by symmetry, $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$.  Also, coterminal angles have the same sine since they intersect the unit circle at the same point.  Hence, 
$$\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$$ 
if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
We wish to solve the equation 
$$\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$$
Since a particular solution is 
$$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
we need to find all values of $x$ that satisfy the equation
$$\sin x = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
Using the formulas above for the solution of the equation $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$, we obtain
$$x = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
\begin{align*}
x & = \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
  & = \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

So you are right that a solution to $sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ is $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$, however, note that this is far from the only solution. If we look at the geometric definition of the $sin(x)$ function, we see that there are many values of $x$ for which the y-value of the unit circle are 1. The first is $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$, however, that is only the coordinate in the first quadrant. There is also a coordinate $(\frac{-\sqrt3}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ which will come when $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$. Now also note that a rotation of $2\pi$ will get you back to the same value, and so the solutions are not only $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$, but $x=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi k$ and $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, for every equation of this kind there are always two solutions?

Comment: For essentially all equations with $sin(x)=a$ for some value a, yes. The only exceptions are the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=sin(x)$, 1 and -1. Have a look at [this](http://imgur.com/a/uOBQ1). You can see that within any one period of the sin(x) function there will be 2 points of for a non-zero value between 0 and 1 (as shown with $y=\frac{1}{2}$). The only exceptions are y=-1, y=1 (as they are extremities) and y=0 (though I'm not completely sure if that counts as it passes through three times if the domain is 0 to 2pi inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the properties: $\;\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ and $\sin x$ has period $2\pi$. There results the equation $\sin x=\sin \theta$ has as solutions:
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv\theta\\x\equiv\pi-\theta
\end{cases}\mod2\pi$$